# SQL Server Connection Timeout Not working

Tags: sql-server, connection, timeout

I've changed the Connection Timeout to 10 seconds.
'...;Connection Timeout=10;..."
The code uses EF 6, .Net 4.5.1.
SQL Server Client has both tcp/ip and Named Pipes enabled.
Disconnected from the Network and then start debugging.
The timeout error happens at the 1 minute mark.

This seems to indicate the error happens when the sql server is not located.
Is SQL Server Ado.net client code is setting the network timeout?

I had thought this was fixed a while ago, like back in 2.0 days.

Comment: When using a standard `SQLConnection`, the timeout works (just tested with 4.5). Perhaps the place you are setting timeout is not being used for your test. Try stepping through the code to see what the timeout says. You may be setting it for design-time, not run-time.

Comment: Try disconnecting from the network to do your test. I think it's the network timeout happening, not the actual communication after the network connection is set up. Problem was and I guess still is buried in the sql server connection code.